# How to use the _S framework

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, framework

I've previously done Tumblr themes and this is my first Wordpress theme. After initially starting out a theme from scratch I decided to switch to _S due to time constraints.

My issue is that I may have misunderstood what _S is, so I'm here to get some clarity on a few things.

1. First off, I decided to go with the _S theme as what I understand is that it has all the functionality side of things already done (functions & other PHP) as the site I'm intending to make does not need fancy functionality right now, so this would let me get on with the design aspects. Is this a correct assumption and what exactly is _S?
2. I had a look at the `style.css` as well as layout folder, and my main issue is here. I'm intending to build a site with my own particular layout so should I replace all the CSS in `style.css` with my own? I'm not sure if I should as most of it seemed just to be good practice CSS to make sure things work but could I be wrong in this and is it there more for stylistic purposes? Then there's the issue with my own, actual CSS for the site, should I just place it under the CSS already in `style.css` or make it on a new file and have that linked in?

Basically all I want to do is get on with detailing how the particulars of my visuals are at the moment, can i do this with _S?

Also would _S allow me to add my own particular functionality easily or would I be better off with making my own parent theme as I want to avoid modifying a theme?

Answer (score 1):

The `readme` in the [theme repository](https://github.com/automattic/_s) answers your questions already: replace what you don’t need, and add your own code to the theme’s `style.css` and `functions.php`.

The theme isn’t meant to be *complete*, it is really just a start. You can do whatever you want, and it will be fine.

### Examples

I would change the font size handling. In `_s` it is set in `px`. This isn’t really user-friendly, because it might break when a user has set a minimum font size. You can replace it with better values sized in `em`.

There is a function `_s_wp_title()` to change the output of `wp_titel()`. This is plugin territory, so you can just remove it.

Comment: Agreed. It's simply a good quality starting point. It's akin to starting with an outline. Feel free to rip out or rewrite anything that you want. Don't use it as a parent theme, it should literally be the actual theme you use.